# Unable to rebase pulled changes onto master

Tags: git, rebase

I pulled some remote using 'git pull --rebase' and ran into some conflicts, so I checked out my versions of those files using 'git checkout --ours filename'.  At this point "git status" did not show any changes, so I could essentially not complete the merge, and 'git rebase --continue' did not work.  Now the state of my project is, origin/master has branched where my last push was made, and my master branch is not merged in.  I want to rebase these pulled changes on top of master.  Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you checked out those file? It is unclear in what state are you now. You need to resolve all merge conflicts and move to the next commit while rebasing.

Do it in more manual way:

```
// you are on master with clean working dir.
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
// commits from your local master are applied one by one in order on top of origin/master.  You resolve all conflicts and proceed with git rebase --continue.
```